# Oledb skips the first column of excel file. The first column is empty

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, xls, oledbcommand

The problem is that the first column is empty and it can not be read.
[image]

To read the file, I wrote the following code:

```
            MyConnection = new OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + "'" + filename + "'" + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO;TypeGuessRows=0\"");

            DtSet = new DataSet();
            MyConnection.Open();
            var dt = MyConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

                MyCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [$first]", MyConnection);
                MyCommand.Fill(DtSet); // filldata

                dataExcel.AddRange(fillData(DtSet.Tables["Table"]).Select(info => info.ToList())); 
            }

List<List<string>> fillData(DataTable DtSet) //reader
        {
            List<List<string>> data = new List<List<string>>();
            foreach (DataRow item in DtSet.Rows)
            {
                if (item == null) continue;
                List<string> gettedData = new List<string>();
                int i = 0;
                foreach (var columnitem in item.ItemArray)
                {
                    if (i == 0 && columnitem.ToString() == "") ;
                    else gettedData.Add(columnitem.ToString()); //add data

                    i++;
                }
                data.Add(gettedData);
            }
            return data;
        }
```

This code works but the first column, he does not see. Thank you!

Comment: This is by design.  It's the same mechanism that prevents you from getting _every following_ column that is also empty.  You might be able to get it by replacing `SELECT *` with a specific reference for the columns you want.

Comment: The fact that I am using this code to extract data from different files. different structure

Comment: Have you tried removing `TypeGuessRows=0` from your connection string? I tested using Excel.12 and for me, all the in-between empty columns _are selected_.  So perhaps it's driver-specific, as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! nothing works. still does not see the column.

Comment: did you ever resolve this?  I'm having the same problem